# how to return one of the duplicates from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table where i have a duplicate records with different coulmn names 
for eg

```
id  classname
123 class1
123 unknown
```

then i also have some tags with only unique class name 
fr eg

```
id  classname
124  class2 
125  unknown
```

so now i run a select query i get result

```
id  classname
123 class1
123 unknown
124 class2
125 unknown
```

i want to return values in such a way that one of the duplicates is selected

```
id classnae
123 class1 
124 class2 
125 unknown
```

the above mentione is what i have to get as result .
I was using left outer join to write this .

```
select t.id,t.classname from Table1 t 
left outer join 
(select id,classname from Table1 GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(id) > 1 ) 
s on s.Tagname = t.TagName
```

but i am getting the same no of records that i used to get earlier with duplicates.

need help to write this

Comment: Please give us a rule by which we can choose *which* of the `classname` values should be in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
 MAX(id) id, 
 classname 
from(
     select * from table1 union
     select * from table2
)x group by classname
```

Comment: I didn't get you, given query returns your expected result no?

Comment: thanks for the query that is working fine , suffices my requirement , but i want my result set only to give id column instead of both     select distinct id,
(select top 1 classname from table1 t2 where t2.id = t.id and classname!='unknown' order by case classname when 'unknown' then 0 else 1 end) classname
from Table1 t  the above query is wring fine but now i want the ids in my result i.e., means i want only id's column containing one of the duplicates value , could you help on this

Comment: @user2861354 Please add a different set of data and expected output. I am not able to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
select distinct id,
    (select top 1 classname from table1 t2 where t2.id = t.id order by case classname when 'unknown' then 0 else 1 end) classname
from Table1 t
```

I wasn't sure which of the duplicates you want to return as `classname`. You can control id by changing `order by` in the inner query.

If you want to completely remove unknowns

```
select distinct id,
    (select top 1 classname from table1 t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.classname <> 'unknown') classname
from Table1 t
    where t.classname <> 'unknown'
```

Comment: Thanks it was working for me as expected but the condition on which i was trying to pull is not working i was trying to avoid the duplicates with Unknown classname but still since i am selecting top 1 of the class name i have some duplicate rows with top 1 being Unknown so my result is displying unknown class which i dont want

Comment: Check my edit. Hope the syntax works as I'm writing from memory now.

Comment: hi thank u for update , i had modified this according to your edit  but i could still see some duplicates with unknown.

Comment: It should now only give 'unknown' if there are no other records for the same id. Do you want to remove all unknowns completely?

Comment: Check my new version.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment on Szymon's answer try the below query:

```
    select distinct id,
(select top 1 classname from table1 t2 where t2.id = t.id and classname!='unknown' order by case classname when 'unknown' then 0 else 1 end) classname
from Table1 t
```

as you required:: you don't want to get the class with 'unknow' name.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
select * into #tbl from(
select 123 id ,'class1' classname
union select 123,'unknown'
union select 124,'class2'
union select 125,'unknown'
) A

select * from #tbl

select MAX(ID),classname 
from #tbl 
group by classname

drop table #tbl
```

This gets the same result as you have shown in the question. But I am concerned about MAX(ID) because it only give the larget ID of the duplicate entries of classname. So choose accordingly to your needs.

Comment: the amount od duplicates i have is 9500+ records i cannot modif using union i guess

Comment: I used union for making a temp table only. In your case you do not need that.